# Is it possible for a Wizard/Cleric to obtain Trackless Step?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, wizard, cleric

My player, after getting a few levels in Cleric and Wizard as well, decided to become an Arcane Hierophant. I suggested him a few other similar arcane/divine classes, but he was not satisfied with them.

I want to play by the rules and I wonder if there is something, that could give him **Trackless Step** without a need to level in other classes.
I couldn't find any appropriate feat neither an item. Is it even possible?

Comment: Does it have to be "trackless step" or is a similar effect / solution welcomed as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [Trackless step](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/druid.html#druid-trackless-step) is difficult for a nondruid to acquire

No feat, item, or conveniently available class provides access to the extraordinary ability trackless step. (Although several prestige classes *do* grant the ability—the [List of Stuff](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1412.0) by *Min/Max Boards* user Surreal is handy here—, no class is *convenient*.) However, the race bamboo spirit folk (*Oriental Adventures* 14, 15) has the special ability trackless step as a racial trait. A player could urge the DM to customize the chart used for [*reincarnate*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsPtoR.html#reincarnate) (*PH* 270) [(like at least one professional has done)](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebds/20051024a) so that the chart includes bamboo spirit folk then have the character repeatedly suicide after which a game druid casts *last breath* (*Spell Compendium* 140) until the process yields the result bamboo spirit folk. This *will* probably be expensive, though.

Alternatively, as KRyan's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/90174/8610) mentions, with the DM's permission, a humanoid creature could possibly use the spell [*alter self*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsAtoB.html#alter-self) just to take the form of a bamboo spirit folk when leveling up (or, if the DM insists, for a longer period using a custom magic item).

Other than this, with the DM's approval, an elf can take the feat **Improved Greenlore** (*Birthright Conversion Manual* (Ver. 2.1) (Apr. 2001) 10) which grants the elf both the special abilities trackless step *and* [woodland stride](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/druid.html#druid-woodland-stride). The feat has no prerequisites other than being an elf, and [*Birthright.net*](http://www.birthright.net/), the site whence comes the *Conversion Manual* (also called the *Third Edition Birthright Rulebook*), is approved by Wizards of the Coast *via* the company's [license for fan sites](http://www.birthright.net/forums/showwiki.php?title=Birthright_license_agreement). The text is available for download on that site after registering. A table certainly might ban the text so ask first, but it *is*—if you tilt your head and squint—at least *kind of*, in the abstract, approved for general use? It's worth talking to the DM, at least.

Because the prestige class arcane heirophant (*Races of the Wild* 108-13)—if its requirements are met conventionally by a Clr4/Wiz3—is usually a power-*down*, a generous DM may allow simply purchasing an item that grants the wearer or bearer the special ability trackless step. Such an item (probably magic boots) will have a cost determined by the DM, but from 15,000 gp to 20,000 gp seems appropriate using Improved Greenlore as a guideline for Magic Items that Grant Feats (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 128).

Answer (score 1):

Bamboo spirit folk from *Oriental Adventures* have it as a racial feature.

Spirit folk are Humanoids, so a humanoid spellcaster could cast *alter self* to become one. Strictly speaking, one could qualify for arcane hierophant by being subject to an *alter self* effect during level-up, and from then on retain the class features and right to take more levels of the class, even after *alter self* wears off.

That kind of thing is generally frowned upon (and, because I suggest you shouldn’t set that precedent, I’d be inclined to just waive the trackless step requirement rather than allow that), but it might suggest acceptable approaches. For example, some item of constant *alter self* could be possible. Or just an item of constant *pass without trace*, or an item that magically grants trackless step itself (you know that such an item would at most cost what an item of constant *alter self* would).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48243/discussion-on-answer-by-kryan-is-it-possible-for-a-wizard-cleric-to-obtain-track).